# Ensuring that all radio buttons are checked on a page.

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page with a lot of radio buttons below. It is mandary for my users to
check one on every row. I am looking for a way where on click of my save button
I run a check on all the radio buttons and make sure they are checked with limited javascript or jquery code.

How can I acheive this?

```
            <div id="HealthCheck1">           
                <div id="HCBudget">
                    <label for="budgethealth">Budget Health</label>
                    <span class="radiored"><input type="radio" id="bhred" name="budgethealth" value="red" @(Model.BudgetHealth == "3" ? "checked='checked'" : "")></input></span>
                    <span class="radioyellow"><input type="radio" id="bhyellow" name="budgethealth" value="yellow" @(Model.BudgetHealth == "2" ? "checked='checked'" : "")></input></span>
                    <span class="radiogreen"><input type="radio" id="bhgreen" name="budgethealth" value="green" @(Model.BudgetHealth == "1" ? "checked='checked'" : "")></input></span>
                </div>
                <hr>
                <div id="HCTeam">
                    <label for="teamhealth">Team Health</label>
                    <span class="radiored"><input type="radio" id="thred" name="teamhealth" value="red" @(Model.TeamHealth == "3" ? "checked='checked'" : "")></input></span>
                    <span class="radioyellow"><input type="radio" id="thyellow" name="teamhealth" value="yellow" @(Model.TeamHealth == "2" ? "checked='checked'" : "")></input></span>
                    <span class="radiogreen"><input type="radio" id="thgreen" name="teamhealth" value="green" @(Model.TeamHealth == "1" ? "checked='checked'" : "")></input></span>
                </div>
                <hr>
                <div id="HCRisk">
                    <label for="riskhealth">Risk Health</label>
                    <span class="radiored"><input type="radio" id="rhred" name="riskhealth" value="red" @(Model.RiskHealth == "3" ? "checked='checked'" : "")></input></span>
                    <span class="radioyellow"><input type="radio" id="rhyellow" name="riskhealth" value="yellow" @(Model.RiskHealth == "2" ? "checked='checked'" : "")></input></span>
                    <span class="radiogreen"><input type="radio" id="rhgreen" name="riskhealth" value="green" @(Model.RiskHealth == "1" ? "checked='checked'" : "")></input></span>
                </div>
            </div>      
            <div id="ProgHealthStat" class="btnholder">
                <button id="Save" class="sendbtn">Save Changes</button>
            </div>
```

I tried this line of code but no luck. I kept receiving the alert despite that the radio buttons were all checked.

```
            $('div.HealthCheck1:not(:has(:radio:checked))')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give each div that has radio buttons in it a class property (e.g. `class="foo"`). Then you can do:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#Save').on('click', function() {
    if ($('.foo:not(:has(:radio:checked))').length) {
      alert('Please finish filling out the form');
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="HealthCheck1">
    <div id="HCBudget" class="foo">
        <label for="budgethealth">
            Budget Health
        </label>
        <span class="radiored">
            <input id="bhred" name="budgethealth" type="radio" value="red"/>
        </span>
        <span class="radioyellow">
            <input id="bhyellow" name="budgethealth" type="radio" value="yellow"/>
        </span>
        <span class="radiogreen">
            <input id="bhgreen" name="budgethealth" type="radio" value="green"/>
        </span>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div id="HCTeam" class="foo">
        <label for="teamhealth">
            Team Health
        </label>
        <span class="radiored">
            <input id="thred" name="teamhealth" type="radio" value="red"/>
        </span>
        <span class="radioyellow">
            <input id="thyellow" name="teamhealth" type="radio" value="yellow"/>
        </span>
        <span class="radiogreen">
            <input id="thgreen" name="teamhealth" type="radio" value="green"/>
        </span>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div id="HCRisk" class="foo">
        <label for="riskhealth">
            Risk Health
        </label>
        <span class="radiored">
            <input id="rhred" name="riskhealth" type="radio" value="red"/>
        </span>
        <span class="radioyellow">
            <input id="rhyellow" name="riskhealth" type="radio" value="yellow"/>
        </span>
        <span class="radiogreen">
            <input id="rhgreen" name="riskhealth" type="radio" value="green"/>
        </span>
    </div>
    </hr>
    </hr>
</div>
<div class="btnholder" id="ProgHealthStat">
    <button class="sendbtn" id="Save">
        Save Changes
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: If they have to select one from each category don't you also need `> div` so it performs the check on each of the child nodes?

Comment: @Nat you're right, thanks! I've updated my answer so that it actually works.

Comment: I will test this shortly and get back to you. Thanks guys.